# How to zoom in On my location while still maintaining the bounds on Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming, bounds

This is a snippet of my code.

```
//position on Center

CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
       new LatLng(14.635356, 121.03272914)).zoom(15).build();

map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

//within bounds
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(QC.getCenter(), 12));
```

On the first comment, the bounds I set are displayed. However, If I click the button to show my current location, the map doesn't zoom in to my location(that's what it was supposed to do) and just maintains the zoom level.

However, if I do this

```
//within bounds
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(QC.getCenter(), 12));

//position on Center

CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
       new LatLng(14.635356, 121.03272914)).zoom(15).build();

map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

The camera animates to my current location and zoom level, however the bounds I set are not displayed.

I would like to know it is possible to show the bounds I set and the zoom level at the start, then zoom in to my location and zoom in. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

try this code to set bounds. after setting these bounds set you position in map.

```
LatLngBounds boundsLatLng = new LatLngBounds.Builder()
    .include(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(bounds.get(0).get("lat")),Double.parseDouble(bounds.get(0).get("lng") )))
    .include(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(bounds.get(1).get("lat")),Double.parseDouble(bounds.get(1).get("lng") )))
    .build();

    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(boundsLatLng,50));
```

set bounds variable this way

```
List<HashMap<String,String>> bounds = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        HashMap<String, String> p = new HashMap<String, String>();
    p.put("lat", "29.373");p.put("lng", "23");
    HashMap<String, String> p1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    p1.put("lat", "39.373");p1.put("lng", "43");
    bounds.add(p);bounds.add(p1);
```

Comment: how are you setting bounds variable?
its type is 
List<HashMap<String,String>> bounds = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
are you setting it properly?
something like this
  HashMap<String, String> p = new HashMap<String, String>();
  p.put("lat", "29.373");p.put("lng", "23");
  HashMap<String, String> p1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
  p.put("lat", "39.373");p.put("lng", "43");
  bounds.add(p);bounds.add(p1);

Answer (score 1):

Try `LatLngBounds`

Eg:-
 suppose I have a `GoogleMap mMap;` Then,

```
LatLng northeast=new LatLng(14.635356, 121.03272914);
LatLng southwest=new LatLng(15.635356, 120.03272914);// give values as your need
LatLngBounds mbounds=new LatLngBounds(southwest, northeast);
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(mbounds, 3));// Here 2nd parameter '3' is padding.
```

This will automatically zoom to include bounds.

Comment: actually the bounds I set are working. the problem I am having is that, when I click the button to find my location , the map doesn't zoom in it just maintains the "view" where the bounds are seen. Is it possible to zoom in after seeing the "bounds"?